# B450 Gaming X (rev. 1.x) is compatibility with ubuntu

Tags: compatibility, motherboard, gigabyte

I am planning on building a PC.
And I was wondering if ubuntu is compatible with my motherboard: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450-Gaming-X-rev-1x/sp#sp
Also are there any bios & drivers for my motherboard
Please Help

Comment: Bios is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Search this site for b450.  There are 128 questions that match.